# How to convert uneven XML (data with different fields in each record) to table format (2D array)?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a program that is going to scan a directory of audio files, extract the tag data for each file and convert the data to a format that can easily be turned into a database. The issue is that each record will not necessarily have the same number of fields which makes conversion to a 2D format, such as delimited text, difficult.

Some of the tags are lists of items and will expand the number of fields in a record.  Once I scan 10k+ files for 210 different tags I'm going to end up with a bunch of mixed up data and I have no idea what to do with it.

This is what I have ...

```
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>A</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>B</ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Rock</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>D</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>E</ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value>F</ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Hip Hop</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value></ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Techno</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
```

and I want to convert it to the following

```
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>A</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>B</ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value></ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Rock</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>D</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>E</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value>F</ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Hip Hop</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
<record>
    <AudioInfo.Bitrate>320</AudioInfo.Bitrate>
    <AudioInfo.Channels>2</AudioInfo.Channels>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value></ID3V2.CommentsList_0.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value></ID3V2.CommentsList_1.Value>
    <ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value></ID3V2.CommentsList_2.Value>
    <ID3V2.Genre.Value>Techno</ID3V2.Genre.Value>
</record>
```

I have been racking my brain over this and I don't know what to do.  Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq.  The XDocument doc is updates to include all the missing tags. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> records = doc.Descendants("record").ToList();

            List<string> uniquetagNames = records.SelectMany(x => x.Elements().Select(y => y.Name.LocalName)).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (XElement record in records)
            {
                XElement newRecord = new XElement("record");
                foreach (string uniquetagName in uniquetagNames)
                {
                    if (record.Element(uniquetagName) == null)
                    {
                        newRecord.Add(new XElement(uniquetagName));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRecord.Add(record.Element(uniquetagName));
                    }
                }
                record.ReplaceWith(newRecord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```